# Best Practice: handling properties that don't exist

Tags: powershell, properties

A common pattern I see in example PowerShell scripts is something like this

```
If ($object.property -ne $true) {  
    $object.property = $true   
}
```

But this fails to address the situation where a particular instance of $object doesn't include property, and will error in that case. I ran into it specifically when iterating over the network adapters to enable WOL, and an adapter doesn't support it. In any case, one approach would be to use Try/Catch, but my sense is that exceptions are to be avoided if there is a way to validate things before hand. So, am I correct in feeling like Try/Catch should be an approach of last resort? Or is it basically fine in PowerShell to use Try/Catch as the primary method of addressing errors? And if try/Catch is not the best answer, how does one go about testing to see if a particular object has a property so as to simply skip the assignment if it doesn't? What little I have found have been really ugly/messy approaches, and/or a try/catch in a helper function, so you just don't see if in most of your code. None of which is inherently better, other than the helper function addressing code readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches that I am aware of for this. [mjolinor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29651395/3829407) stole the first one.

The second would be to use `Get-Member`

```
If($object | Get-Member -MemberType Properties).Name -contains $property){
    $object.$property = $true
}
```

Comment: Matt, this seems like the most elegant solution I have seen, assuming it works universally. Or perhaps I just need to learn two or three approaches for different situations and get over the "lack of consistency" issues I have. I was unable to get mjolinor's solution to work, but I'll call that weekend homework to explore. ;) Maybe being in v2 is the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Gordon I think you might have an issue in v2 using the dot notation like mjolinor was. `prop.prop.prop` I think it needs to have minimum v3.0. His solution does still work though. Glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
if ($object.psobject.properties.name -contains $property)
  { $object.$property = $true }
```

Comment: I guess that does not work for everything? I would have assumed `(gwmi win32_networkadapter).Psobject.properties.name` that would have worked but it does not appear to. WMI was the only example i could find.

Comment: @Matt - Works for me (running V4), but it returns an array so you have to iterate that and check each adapter returned.

Comment: Silly me. I was checking the properties of an array not its elements. Thanks.